# Text editing: switch to Override mode

Tags: text-editor, textmate

In insert mode, the text in front of the cursor is pushed forward when new text is inserted. For example, if the cursor is at position `^` and the word `word3` is typed:

```
word1 word2
      ^
```

The result would be:

```
word1 word3word2
           ^
```

In override mode the result would be:

```
word1 word3
           ^
```

**Can I switch between [Insert mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) and Override mode in OSX text editing?**

Comment: please provide hardware information-model.

Comment: OSX Lion, MacBook Pro. I don't really understand the downvotes, by the way. It's a real question - I would be very happy to switch to override mode in some code editing scenarios.

Comment: It was not me, I can not downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, normal OS X text views don't support anything like that.

In TextMate 1 you can use ⌥⌘O (Edit > Mode > Overwrite Mode).

In Word 2011 for Mac you can go to View > Toolbars > Customize Toolbars & Menus and drag Commands > All Commands > Overtype to a menu.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to one earlier answer, in the 2011 Word for Mac, you can

1. Go to the Tools menu,
2. Select Customize Keyboard
3. Select All Commands in the left-hand list of the dialog box
4. Look for Overtype in the right-hand list, and
5. Assign your own keyboard shortcut that will switch you between insert and overwrite/overytype.